# How to fetch all contents from MediaFields via GraphQL using OrchardCore CMS?

Tags: .net, graphql, orchardcms, orchard-modules

I want to build a static website. To include media items (files) in the static website I want to fetch them using GraphQL.

All the contents I want are stored inside a Media FieldType in OrchardCore CMS.

Who knows how to fetch them via GraphQL?

Thanks in advance, Jordy

Answer (score 1):

I would use https://gitter.im/OrchardCMS/OrchardCore the community is very active on this platform.